# Hidden corners become visible when animating in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a `ul` with `border-radius: 10px; overflow:hidden` and inside I have multiple `li`s.

Normally, the `ul` corners hide the inner content. But in Chrome, when using jQuery to animate (fade) the `li`s, during the animation, the `li` corners become visible.

Once the animation is complete, the corners of the `li`s return to being hidden.

What can I do to prevent this ?

This only happens in Webkit browsers: Chrome and Safari.

**HTML :**

```
<ul>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
    <li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS :**

```
ul {
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo?

Comment: I've seen this question/problem before. Possibly a WebKit bug.

Comment: I see this during css animations for overflow:hidden things outside of border radiuses. I expect it's a webkit bug, like @MattBall says.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// give specific border-radius to first ans last li
$('li:first').css('border-radius', '0 10px 0 0');
$('li:last').css('border-radius', '0 0 10px 0');
```

**NOTE** You may also use CSS

[DEMO shows a sample animation](http://jsfiddle.net/thesystemrestart/6NEGB/4/)

Comment: Yes, that works but it is a workaround rather than a fix for the source of the problem.

Comment: @jsgroove Welcome to web development! :)